# Custom async vue-validator breaks validation component

Tags: validation, promise, vue.js

I'm trying to perform asynchronous validation for one of my Vue.js components using [vue-validator](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator), following [this example](http://vuejs.github.io/vue-validator/async.html). I'd like to check if the email provided by a user is already taken.

This is the validator implementation I'm currently struggling with:

```js
Vue.validator('emailUnique', {
    message: 'this e-mail address has already been taken',
    check: function (val) {
        return Vue.http({
            url: '/validate/email-unique',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: val
            }
        }).then(
            function (response) { // success
                console.log('success');
                return Promise.resolve();
            },
            function (response) { // error
                console.log('error');
                return Promise.reject();
            }
        ).catch(function(error) {
            console.log('catch');
            return Promise.reject();
        });
    }
});
```

Which I use in my component like so:

```html
<div>
<validator name="userValidator">
  <form novalidate class="form-group" v-on:submit.prevent="submitUser">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control"
               placeholder="jon@greatesthits.com"
               v-model="user.email" required v-validate:email="{ required: true, email: true, emailUnique: true }">
        <div class="form-validation-error" v-if="$userValidator.email.required && $userValidator.email.touched">
          <span>this field is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-validation-error" v-if="$userValidator.email.email && $userValidator.email.touched">
          <span>not a valid e-mail address</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-validation-error" v-if="$userValidator.email.emailUnique && $userValidator.email.touched">
          <span>this e-mail address has already been taken</span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</validator>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, this breaks the entire validation object for email:

```
[Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "$userValidator.email.required && $userValidator.email.touched".
TypeError: scope.$userValidator.email is undefined
```

If I don't register the `emailUnique` validator, the other two validation rules work fine.
Also, the request to `/validate/email-unique` is posted correctly and receives the expected return value (just a json_encoded response with `true/false`), and I see the corresponding `console.log()` output (`'success', 'error', 'catch'`), so I'm guessing the return value for the check function isn't correct and causes `vue-validator` to fail.

`Vue.http` does return a `Promise` though, so according to the docs and the example linked to above this should be fine. I also tried to return `true` or `false` from within the `.then()` clause, yet `Vue.http` still returns a `Promise` (which apparently troubles `vue-validator` -- maybe the `Promise` object I'm returning is not of the form `vue-validator` expects?).

Any tipps on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this problem persist if you turn `vue.config.debug` to false? There is an issue where Vue tries to evaluate `scope.$userValidator.email.required` BEFORE `vue-validator` actually creates that variable. This only flags an error during debug mode and works otherwise.  The variable will EVENTUALLY exist and work, just not at the time it's initially evaluated.  This is an issue with the lifecycle of the directive that will require some tweaks to vue core.

See here: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator/issues/99

I do not believe this issue has been resolved that I know of.  You may try upgrading `Vue` and `vue-validator` to the latest versions if you haven't already. I know @kazupon, creator of `vue-validator` has a contribution in `vue 1.0.19` that relates to this, though not sure if it was fixed: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/releases/tag/v1.0.19

edit: **this is fixed in new versions**. `vue 1.0.19` added support for terminal directives.  From the docs:

> Vue compiles templates by recursively walking the DOM tree. However when it encounters a terminal directive, it will stop walking that element’s children.

In short, Vue will no longer try to compile the elements inside a validator, and will leave it to the plugin.  Make sure you have validator 2.0.0, which was released just a couple days after the vue core update: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-validator/releases/tag/v2.0.0

Comment: At the time of writing I was still on `vue 1.0.16` (but already on `vue-validator 2.0.0`), updating vue to `vue 1.0.21` solved the issue. Thanks a lot!